# Find the orthogonal projection of b onto col A

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

**When finding the orthogonal projection for this problem, why were those vectors added? Aren't the vectors normally subtracted for Gram-Schmidt and finding projections?**

Also, how do you carry out the Gram Schmidt process for doing part (a)?

Comment: Gram Schmidt is used to orthonormalise an ordered list of vectors. One point in having an orthonormal list of vectors is that the projections are trivial to compute (as above).

Comment: The Gram-Schmidt process was already done to $u_1$ and $u_2$.  The part below that (where the vectors are being added) is a [projection of $\mathbf b$ onto the subspace](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112728/how-do-i-exactly-project-a-vector-onto-a-subspace) spanned by the columns of $A$.

Comment: And you told me in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064169/finding-an-orthogonal-projection-b-onto-col-a) that you knew how to do Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization.  Have you forgotten since then?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately...I'm not sure how to apply it to this problem. What do I set as v1 and v2? When I set b as v1 and the first column vector as v2, it doesn't work out...

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: I understand how to do this conceptually, but what two vectors do I even use for Gram Schmidt orthogonalization? If I wanted to do it for the beginning and use matrix A and vector b, then how would one go about setting the vectors for Gram Schmidt?

Comment: For example, if I let v1 = b and v2 = first column of A, then I do not get the correct values for the Gram Schmidt computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column space of $A$ is $\operatorname{span}\left(\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 4 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}\right)$.

Those two vectors are a *basis* for $\operatorname{col}(A)$, but they are not normalized.

NOTE: In this case, the columns of $A$ are already orthogonal so you don't need to use the Gram-Schmidt process, but since in general they won't be, I'll just explain it anyway.

To make them orthogonal, we use the Gram-Schmidt process:

$w_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $w_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 4 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} - \operatorname{proj}_{w_1} \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 4 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$, where $\operatorname{proj}_{w_1} \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 4 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$ is the orthogonal projection of $\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 4 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$ onto the subspace $\operatorname{span}(w_1)$.

In general, $\operatorname{proj}_vu = \dfrac {u \cdot v}{v\cdot v}v$.

Then to normalize a vector, you divide it by its norm:

$u_1 = \dfrac {w_1}{\|w_1\|}$ and $u_2 = \dfrac{w_2}{\|w_2\|}$.

The norm of a vector $v$, denoted $\|v\|$, is given by $\|v\|=\sqrt{v\cdot v}$.

This is how $u_1$ and $u_2$ were obtained from the columns of $A$.

Then the orthogonal projection of $b$ onto the subspace $\operatorname{col}(A)$ is given by $\operatorname{proj}_{\operatorname{col}(A)}b = \operatorname{proj}_{u_1}b + \operatorname{proj}_{u_2}b$.

Comment: Yeah, it's a tricky thing! Thanks for your explanation though, I get everything else, I was just getting stuck on the first step for some odd reason. The explanation as to the projections and how they are summed is helpful and illuminating, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Questions (a) and (b) turn out to be the same. By definition, the least squares solution is the $\DeclareMathOperator{\argmin}{\arg\!\min} \argmin_x \Vert Ax-b \Vert_2$. It's easy to prove that the minimum is attained for the orthogonal projection, i.e. for $x:(Ax-b)\perp col(A)$, or in matrix notation,
$$
A^t(Ax-b)=A^tAx-A^tb=0
$$
If the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, the solution is
$$x=(A^t A)^{-1}A^tb$$
It is both (b) the least squares solution and (a) the coordinates of the orthogonal projection in the basis of the columns-vectors of $A$, $Ax$ being the same vector given in the standard basis of the ambient space.