# Show that a Norm Obtains a Minimum

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, normed-spaces

Consider a real normed vector space, and a collection of linearly independent vectors $x_i \in X$ for $i=1,2,3,4..., n$. For a fixed $y \in X$ show that:

$\inf_{\alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}, i=1,2,3...,n} ||{y-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_ix_i}||$ assumes a minimum.

So this is an engineering math course and were going over function fitting. First off, I know that infimum and minimum are not the same thing, but the way the problem is posed seems to imply that there is an absolute minimum and it is equal the infimum of the set. I think it may that I'm not understanding his notation.

Conceptually, as I see it, if $X$ were the space of continuous functions, and we wanted to fit a polynomial to that continuous function, we certainly would want to minimize the norm difference between our function, $y$, and the fit polynomial $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_ix_i$. In this case the $x_i$ could be a basis of $n$th order polynomials. Hence, if we find a minimum norm value and the vector $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_ix_i$ that generates it, then we've found a "best" fit approximation for $y$.

My first thought to go about showing a minimum exists was to say that we could simply go through every possible $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_ix_i$, evaluate the norm with $y$, and then find one particular selection of $x_i$ and $\alpha_i$ that generates the minimum. However, since the $\alpha_i$ can be any numbers, I can't "check" every possible fit function. So this won't work.

Another small note I made is that $0$ is always a bound I can make below by properties of norms, but I'm unsure of how to refine the minimum value from that point.

Comment: Aren't norms continuous? So close to zero, your norm is arbitrarily close to zero.

Comment: I know the absolute minimum value it can obtain is zero, but I don't think I'm guaranteed that there exists a selection of $x_i$ and $\alpha_i$ to make the norm difference zero in all cases.

Comment: Could calculate the difference from $y$ to the space spanned by the "$x_i$"s. I think it's called the "perpendicular distance" from $y$ to this space.

Comment: I believe an infimum is gauranteed here

Comment: Look here maybe: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112728/how-do-i-exactly-project-a-vector-onto-a-subspace

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one answer:

If a matrix $X$ has linearly independent columns, then there is some $k>0$ such that $\|Xz \| \ge  k \|z\|$ for all $z$.

Let $f(\alpha) = \|X \alpha -y\|$, where $X$ is the matrix composed of the vectors $x_k$. Note that $f(\alpha) \ge 0$ and let $m = \inf_\alpha f(\alpha)$.
We have $f(\alpha) \ge \|X \alpha \| - \|y\| \ge k \|\alpha \| - \|y\|$.

In particular, if $\| \alpha \| > {1 \over k} (m+1+\|y\|)$ we have
$f(\alpha) > m+1$, and so the set $\{ \alpha | f(\alpha) \le m+1 \}$ is non empty and compact and hence $f$ has a minimiser $\alpha_0$
such that $f(\alpha_0) = m$.

Here is a more satisfactory answer, but it relies on the result
that says that a differentiable convex function $f$ is minimised at a point $\alpha^*$ **iff** ${\partial f( \alpha^*) \over \partial \alpha} = 0$.

Ley $\phi(\alpha) = {1 \over 2} \|X\alpha -y \|^2$ (the ${1 \over 2}$
is a conventional convenience, the square makes $\phi$ differentiable everywhere). It should be clear that minimising $\phi$ is the
same as minimising $f$.

We can write $\phi(\alpha) = {1 \over 2}\langle \alpha , X^T X \alpha \rangle - \langle X^T y, \alpha \rangle + {1 \over 2} \|y\|^2$ and 
note that since $X^T X$ is positive semi definite (in fact definite,
in this case) that $\phi$ is convex. Furthermore,
${\partial \phi(\alpha) \over \partial \alpha} = \alpha^T X^T X -y^T X = (X^T(X\alpha-y))^T$.

Hence $\alpha^*$ minimises $\phi$ (and hence $f$) **iff**
$X^T(X\alpha^*-y) = 0$ (these are the normal equations).

In particular, there is **always** a solution to the normal equations
(for **any** matrix $X$, not just one with linearly independent columns), and if $X^T X$ is invertible (**iff** the columns are
linearly independent) then there is a unique minimiser given by
$\alpha^* = (X^TX)^{-1} X^T y$.

If the columns of $X$ are not linearly independent, a solution still exists but is not unique.

Answer (score 0):

The infimum is taken over the set of $\alpha = (\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n)$ which is basically the same as $\mathbb{R}^n$

You can approach the problem as follows (no solution, only outline):

Let $f(\alpha)$ denote the function for which you want to find the minimum, and fix some $d_0 =f(\alpha_0)$

Show that there is a bounded closed set $D$ of such $\alpha$ such that $\alpha\notin D\Rightarrow f(\alpha) > d_0$.

Now you can minimize $f$ over $D$ since $D$ is compact and $f$ is continuous. The minimum will be attainin the interior of $D$ since it will be smaller or equal to $d_0$ and since at the boundary you are already bigger than a fixed value.

Comment: Given the level of the exercise I'm not sure they know or can use Weierstrass theorem in this general form

Answer (score 0):

View your problem this way: you are searching for $\inf_{w\in W}\|y-w\|=:\inf_{w\in W}f(w)$ where $W$ is the subspace spanned by $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ ($f(w)$ is the distance of $w$ from $y$). Now, given that you have the inf $\delta:=\inf_{w\in W}\|y-w\|$ take a sequence $(z_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ of points of $W$ such that $f(z_i)\rightarrow\delta$ it is easy to note that this sequence is limitated, so you can take a subsequence $z_{i_k}\rightarrow \overline{z}$ but $W$ is closed, so $\overline{z}\in W$, we can conclude that $f(\overline{z})=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}f(z_{i_k})=\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}f(z_i)=\delta$ by the continuity of the distance (and - hence - of $f$)

Comment: How do you know that a convergent subsequence exists?

Comment: Because, as I noticed, it is easy to prove that $(z_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded (this depends on the fact that $\ker{(x_1\mid\cdots\mid x_n)}=\{0\}$

Comment: You should point this out, again, I know the result is true, the point here is to help the OP.

Comment: Right. I'm in my first month on MSE. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another way (much more simple if you like geometry) is to take the hortogonal to $W$, $W^\bot$ and its translate, $S:=y+W^\bot$. Now $S\cap W=\{\overline{z}\}$ is the minimum distance point of $W$ from $y$, the one you are searching for.

Comment: You might want to explain what $W$ is?

Comment: It was the same of my first answer, the span of $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$

Comment: I know what you mean by $W$, but another reader may not read all the other answers first before reading yours. The answers should be self contained or at least reference the other answer.

Comment: You are right, but starting with "Another way" is inherently a link which a curious person should easily follow :)

Answer (score -1):

Let $\delta=\inf \left\{\left\lVert{y-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_ix_i}\right\rVert\,;\, (\forall i=1,\dots,n)\,\alpha_i\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$ and $S=\text{span}(x_1,\dots,x_n)$.
Notice that $\lVert x-y\rVert=d(x,y)$.
Then $\delta=\inf_{v\in S} d(y,v)=d(y,S).$

---

> **Proposition:** Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space with the property that closed and bounded sets are compact (for instance, any finite dimensional, normed vector space). Let $K\subset M$ be compact and $C\subset M$ closed.
>
> Then there are $x\in C$ and $y\in K$ with $d(C,K)=d(x,y)$.

*Proof:* Let $(x_n,y_n)\subset C\times K$ be a minimizing sequence for $d(C,K)$, say with $$d(x_n,y_n)<d(C,K)+\frac1n.\tag{*}$$

The existence of such a sequence is guaranteed by the infimum property -- it shows up in the definition of $d(C,K)=\inf_{x\in C,\,y\in K}d(x,y)$.

Because $K$ is compact, there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k},y_{n_k})$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty}y_{n_k}=y\in K$.
In particular, this implies that $\big(d(y_{n_k},y)\big)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded, say by $M\geq 0$.
Then:

$$d(x_{n_k},y)<d(x_{n_k},y_{n_k})+d(y_{n_k},y)<d(C,K)+(M+1)$$

With $R=d(C,K)+(M+1)$, it follows that $\big(x_{n_k}\big)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ lies in $\stackrel{\sim}{K}=\overline{B(R, y)}\cap C$.

As the intersection of two closed sets, $\stackrel{\sim}{K}$ is closed.
Moreover, since $\overline{B(R, y)}$ is bounded, $\stackrel{\sim}{K}$ is also bounded.
It follows that $\stackrel{\sim}{K}$ is compact.

Thus, there must be a subsequence $\left(x_{n_{k_j}},y_{n_{k_j}}\right)$ with $\lim_{j\to\infty} x_{n_{k_j}}=x\in\, \stackrel{\sim}{K}\subset C$.

Since $d:M\times M \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, we have that

$$\lim_{j\to\infty} d\left(x_{n_{k_j}},y_{n_{k_j}}\right)=d(x,y)$$

Moreover, by the defining property $(*)$ of $(x_n,y_n)$, we must have $d(x,y)\leq d(C,K)$.
Since $x\in C$ and $y\in K$, and $d(C,K)$ is the infimum over $x\in C$ and $y\in K$, it must be that $d(x,y)=d(C,K)$, which concludes our proof. $\square$.

---

To see that the proposition applies here, it suffices to consider $M=\text{span}(y,x_1,\dots,x_n)$, $d$ the metric induced by the norm of $X$, $K=\{y\}$ and $C=S$.

Comment: First off, thanks for the reply. Seems Weierstrass is coming into play here. Contains a convergent subsequence, so $\alpha_n$ must be bounded. So $\alpha_n$ converges to an $\alpha$ that minimizes $f$? I have a little background in analysis so I can generally piece this together, but I'm curious now is there any other more intuitive way to approach this? I only ask since the class has no pre-requisites. Leads me to think that either the question does require these foundations, or there's some less foundational way to thinking about it.

Comment: Sorry, one other small question. We seem to only be minimizing over the $\alpha_i$ selection and not the $x_i$ selection. Is this because we can get rid of an $x_i$ by setting the corresponding $\alpha_i$ to 0?

Comment: Yes, the limit of the subsequence must minimize $f$ -- it must attain the infimum -- because of the inequality condition we used to define it.$${}$$
The 'intuitive' approach would be to visualize $S=\text{span}(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ as an $n$-hyperplane on $X$ and the minimum being the distance from $y$ to $S$ (which we generally picture in terms of orthogonal projections). Notice that $\{y\}$ is compact and $S$ is closed, so the distance is always realized as $d(y,s)$ for some $s\in S$.

Comment: In the answer, I'm minimizing over the $\alpha_i$ because that's what you specified the infimum was taken over, in the question, but you could minimize over $v \in S$ in much the same way -- this proof holds in great generality. All we're really need here is that $f$ be continuous and bounded from below. With these hypotheses, we're guaranteed the existence of a minimizing sequence and that this sequence lies in a compact subset of the domain, which in turn guarantees the existence of a convergent subsequence that by construction must converge to the infimum-now-minimum of $f$.

Comment: small proof of copper.hat's remark- the constant function $f=1$ which is continuous has the whole space as the preimage of the compact set ${1}$.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, this was a gross mistake I will correct. What follows is the closed-ness of $C$ which, by itself, does not solve the problem.. The fact that $f$ looks like 'distance to a point' is important here.

Comment: @LeifEricson Please do consider the updated answer, and see the comments as to why the previous answer was not correct.