# Let $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ be a orthonormal set. For $x\in H$ the vector $x-\sum_{k=1}^n \langle x,x_k\rangle x_k$ is orthogonal to $x_k, \forall k$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces

> Let $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ be a finite orthonormal set in a Hilbert Space $H$. Prove that for any $x\in H$ the vector
>   $$x-\sum_{k=1}^n \langle x,x_k\rangle x_k$$
>   is orthogonal to $x_k$ for every $k=1,\dots,n$.

Since $\{ x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ is an orthonormal set, we know that $\langle x_i,x_j\rangle = 0$ for $i\neq j$. We will show that $\langle x-\sum_{k=1}^n \langle x,x_k\rangle x_k , x_k \rangle = 0$ for all $k=1,\dots,n$. Then,

\begin{align}
\langle x-\sum_{k=1}^n \langle x,x_k\rangle x_k , x_k \rangle &= \langle x,x_k\rangle -\langle \sum_{k=1}^n \langle x,x_k\rangle x_k , x_k\rangle \\
&= \langle x,x_k\rangle - \langle \langle x,x_k\rangle x_k, x_k \rangle \\
&= \langle x, x_k \rangle - \langle x,x_k\rangle \langle x_k,x_k\rangle \\
&= \langle x,x_k\rangle - \langle x,x_k\rangle \| x_k\|
\end{align}
So I messed up somewhere. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your set is orthonormal, i.e., $\|x_k\| = 1$. Also note that it should read $\|x_k\|^2$ in the last line.

Comment: Besides the fact that you hadn't noticed the fact that the norm of your vectors is $1$, read your formula as $x-P_V(x)$ where $P_V(x)$ is the orthogonal projection on the subspace defined by the $x_k$. This will give an easier view... See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/112728 and the answers in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mess up, you forgot to notice another fact. The $x_i$ are not only orthogonal, but in fact *orthonormal*

Comment: Oh duh lol thanks:)